# download ftp files to sd card and show in a list view onclcik

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I have downloaded the files from ftp and saving in the sd card.So I want to show the files by fetching from the sd card with listview on click.But its not working for me.

Here is my code

```
     public File f;
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    new Ftpclient().execute();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
        String uri = f.toString(); // error here is null ponter exception

       File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/FtpFiles" + uri);
            // if (uri.contains(".pdf")) {

            Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
            target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");

            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file not found",
                        500).show();
                Log.e("error", "" + e);
            }
            // }
            // }

        }
        class Ftpclient extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    ArrayList<String> temparrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Connecting",
                "please wait");
    }

    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... connection) {
        temparrlist = listftpitems();
        return temparrlist;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                result);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

shows NPE at this line

```
          String uri = f.toString();
```

Help is always appreciated,Thanks

Comment: r u successfully downloded fileS?

Comment: yes I could able to donload the files

Comment: so u just want to show files in listview?

Comment: yes oncliking the listview items i want to show by fetching from sd card folder called FtpFiles

Comment: what type of file it is? only pdfs or others also?

Comment: What happens exactly? What are you willing to solve?

Comment: as of now it has pdf files only

Comment: so when u tap now what happens it opens? or quit?or nay meesage?

Comment: @Shlublu , I have downloaded the pdf files from ftp and saved in sd card and showing the same in list view. so now on clicknig the list view items i want to open the pdf files based on position.

Comment: @adcom , it shows NPE at this line  String uri = f.toString(); // error here is null ponter exception

Comment: What is `f`? I don't see it declared

Comment: what does f var stands for?

Comment: its   public File f; its declared above oncreate,I just edited the question

Comment: Looks like it has never been initialized, it would appear in your code otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

try with lv.invalidate() after lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter) inside onPostExecute

Comment: Why should this make `f` non-null?

Answer (score 0):

The member `File f` is never initialized, so is defaulted to `null`. This is why a NPE is thrown when doing:

```
String uri = f.toString();
```

Comment: ,what if i change this uri like this ArrayList<String> temparrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    temparrlist = listftpitems();

    String uri = temparrlist.get(position).toString();

Comment: How can i initialise that?

Comment: I cannot tell you like that, but you should give a try. Just one thing: in the comment above you are creating a new temparrlist just before assigning it another value.